# tmap in R: using hatched.SpatialPolygons to produce a state polygon with diagonal lines

Tags: r, tmap

I am working with a state-level shapefile of the United States.

```
library(plyr)
library(doBy)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(urbnmapr)
library(haven)
library(sf)
library(tmap)
library(HatchedPolygons)

states_sf = get_urbn_map("states", sf = TRUE)
```

I am plotting the years that a state-level policy went into effect using a color palette in tmap. I would like to indicate the year that a policy was repealed (if relevant) using diagonal lines. Based on this Github thread, I used the hatched.SpatialPolygons function. This works for Arizona: I obtain a layer that I can add to my tmap plot:

```
AZ = states_sf[which(states_sf$state_abbv =="AZ"),]
AZ_H = hatched.SpatialPolygons(AZ, density=0.0001, angle=45)
st_crs(AZ_H) = st_crs(states_sf)
tm_shape(AZ_H) + tm_lines(col = "black")
```

[image: Arizona, displayed with diagonal lines]

But when I try to do this for Louisiana, as follows, R returns an error:

```
LA = states_sf[which(states_sf$state_abbv =="LA"),]
LA_H = hatched.SpatialPolygons(LA, density=0.0001, angle=45)

Error in apply(lines.hatch, 1, function(x) Line(cbind(c(x[1], x[3]), c(x[2],  : 
  dim(X) must have a positive length
```

I thought the error may be due to Louisiana having a less linear boundary than Arizona. But when I tried to smooth the boundary using smooth(), hatched.SpatialPolygons returned the same error message.

Please advise on how to address this error message so that hatched.SpatialPolygons can render a spatial object of diagonal lines filling Louisiana. I am also open to alternative approaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've modified the `HatchedPolygons` library to resolve this error, which occurs when there are polygons too small to contain any lines (see https://github.com/statnmap/HatchedPolygons/pull/9).

Until the pull request is merged into the official HatchedPolygons repo, you can install and use my patched version using:

```r
# install the remotes package if needed
if(!require('remotes'))
  install.packages('remotes')
remotes::install_github("https://github.com/warnes/HatchedPolygons.git")
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the issue was due to islands in the sf object, not the non-linear style of the object's borders. I used the rmapshaper package and the `ms_filter_islands()` function to drop islands, and then hatched.SpatialPolygons produced the shapefile of diagonal lines within the state boundary:

```
LA = states_sf[which(states_sf$state_abbv =="LA"),]
LA2 = ms_filter_islands(LA, min_area = 10000000000)
tm_shape(LA2) + tm_borders()
LA_H = hatched.SpatialPolygons(LA2, density=0.0001, angle=45)
st_crs(LA_H) = st_crs(states_sf)
tm_shape(LA_H) + tm_lines(col = "black")
```

[image]